# Using jQuery scroll to update position make element flicker

Tags: jquery, css, user-interface, scroll

I have a sidebar that I want to be sticking on the right side as soon as user scrolls down to a point where it would disappear.
My first attempt at doing so looked like:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= 524){
    if(!$(".page #sidebar").hasClass("sticky")){
        $(".page #sidebar").addClass("sticky");
    }
    }
    else{
    if($(".page #sidebar").hasClass("sticky")){
        $(".page #sidebar").removeClass("sticky");
    }
    }
});
```

The class *sticky* had a `position: fixed` with a `top` and `right` value, so it would stick correctly in the browser window. Alas, as I was testing, I realized this fault: being the sidebar on the right of the screen, if I would resize the browser window below the resolution I was working with, of course, the sidebar would stay there relatively to browser window.

I came, then, with this solution: putting the sidebar with *absolute positioning* inside another *relatively positioned* container, and then calculating its position with javascript.
Aside of being (I think) unnecessarely heavy, this solution works, but makes the element *flicker* as the `.scroll` event is not firing fast enough. The code is the following:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= 524){
    if(!$(".page #sidebar").hasClass("sticky")){
        $(".page #sidebar").addClass("sticky");
    }
    else{
        $(".page #sidebar").css("top",$(window).scrollTop()-524+"px");
    }
    }
    else{
    if($(".page #sidebar").hasClass("sticky")){
        $(".page #sidebar").removeClass("sticky");
    }
    }
});
```

You can see the live example at: http://www.onewayitalia.it/agenzia-di-comunicazione/web-agency-per-la-realizzazione-di-siti-e-portali-internet/

**Funny is** that, as I am writing, I realize *stackoverflow* is doing the same thing I want to accomplish with the **Similar Questions** sidebar; it seems also to use the *fixed* positioning and don't break on window resize.
Any insight?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to $.animate without queue your calculated position. this might look smoother